# Super user on word table and header row

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have a word document with a table Which has a row header repeating on many pages. I don't want to repeat that in a specific page in between somewhere but continue repeat on other page. So how to do that?. Please reply.

Comment: With one exception (where you want different text on the first page) there is only one situation in which you can do something like this, and that is if you can put the repeating header rows in a table in the header and accept that you have gaps between the table headers and table content, accept that you have to coordinate the table column dimensions, and so on. The basic problem is that even if you try to use field codes (e.g. { IF { PAGE } = 3 "special column header" "regular column header" } ) they do not work because they are only evaluated once, not on each page.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option in Word.

The only solution would be to break the table into three tables with the same headers:

1. The starting part where the header repeats
2. The middle part where the header does not repeat
3. The ending part where the header repeats.